# PlaySound - Latency Between Audio Clips Being Played

Tags: winapi, audio, playsound

Currently, I'm writing code that plays multiple audio clips to essentially form a new sentence from the inputted audio clips.

The code block below is a simplified version of what my code is, but performs what I'm intending it to do:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
// Note: Winmm.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies) is included in Linker >> Input >> Additional Dependencies.

int main() {

     PlaySound(TEXT("conference_room"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
     PlaySound(TEXT("B.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);

}
```

The problem is that there is an inconsistent delay that isn't present when combining the clips manually in an audio editing application. I can't find a solution around this issue, but I have looked into combining audio clips via commands from other libraries, but I've had no luck so far.

If there is a possible solution that involves combining these audio clips in a way that I can use them immediately after [the combined clips will have to go to my project directory]? Otherwise, is there a way to ensure that these commands are executed without delay?

Note: The audio program I used to confirm that the issue was code based is Audacity. As far as I’m aware, Audacity can export lossless audio, and has no issues regarding the addition of silence after an export.

Comment: It takes time to locate a file, open it, and read it, and there is nothing you can do about that. You need to go to a lower abstraction level than `PlaySound`.

Comment: PlaySound() probably opens an audio device, reads the file, analyzes the header, reads a buffer, plays the sound, and then closes the audio device. Next command opens it again, etc. Getting (exclusive?) hardware access needs time, opening and analyzing files takes time...

Comment: @ThomasWeller and molbdnilo - That makes sense. PlaySound is out of the question then.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [XAudio2 API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAudio2). I've never used it, but I guess that this would be the first place to look. I believe this API allows you to play several sounds at once, so it should also be able to do what you want.

Comment: [XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-apis-portal) *can* be used to implement low-latency audio playback. But that would be like writing a GUI application in assembly. A higher-level audio API certainly makes more sense here. There are several to choose from under the [Core Audio APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/core-audio-apis-in-windows-vista) umbrella. A professional audio developer can probably see through this maze, and provide better guidance on which API would make for a good fit.